# Formula returning previous month in `mmmm` format, only returns January

Tags: excel-formula, excel-dates

I have a worksheet that I use every month and would like a formula that automatically updates to the *previous month*.

```
=TEXT(MONTH(TODAY())-1,"mmmm")
```

always returns `January`.

However, just `MONTH(TODAY())-1` correctly returns `11`.

Why then when I format with `TEXT()` does it change to January?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have found `MONTH(TODAY())-1` returns `11`.  The `11` is taken as the number of days from `1/1/1900` when used as you are in the TEXT(), which is the 11th of January 1900 so the month is January.

Use:

```
=TEXT(EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1),"mmmm")
```

Comment: Yes! I was going down that path, thanks for the succinct explanation Scott :D